# Maximizing a stochastic function with Convolution distribution

Tags: mathematical-optimization, convolution

I have a stochastic profit function where I want to maximize with respect to a variable "a". I have written the code like this

```
      NMaximize[\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(2*
     a\), \(\[Infinity]\)]\(400*\((x - 2*a)\)*
    PDF[UniformDistribution[{0, 30}], x] \[DifferentialD]x\)\) - \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(-\[Infinity]\), \(50\)]\(100*x*
    PDF[UniformDistribution[{0, 30}], x] \[DifferentialD]x\)\) - \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(50\), \(\[Infinity]\)]\(150*x*
    PDF[UniformDistribution[{0, 30}], x] \[DifferentialD]x\)\), {a}]
```

This is throwing some warning saying that this is a piecewise function. But, I have tried a similar function with a Uniform distribution where I could get some answers. Why the function is not working in convolution?

Comment: Let us consider the first term  `f[a_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  400*(x - 
     2*a*Piecewise[{{0, x < 0}, {x/225, 
         Inequality[0, LessEqual, x, Less, 15]}, {(30 - x)/225, 
         15 <= x <= 30}}, 0]), {x, 2*a, Infinity}]`. Then `f[1]` outputs `1.711468621650023*10^55897`. This means the integral diverges. You should adjust the formulation of the question.

Comment: I have changed the formulation..can you check now?

Comment: Executing your edited code, I obtain `{3.30192*10^108, {a -> -4.1274*10^105}}` and  a warning about the boundless of the objective function.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

pdf[x_] = PDF[UniformDistribution[{0, 30}], x]
```

[image]

Note that since the [`PDF`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PDF.html) is zero unless `0 <= x <= 30`, the problem can be simplified to

```
Assuming[a ∈ Reals,
 Maximize[
  Integrate[400*(x - 2*a)*pdf[x], {x, 2*a, 30}] - 
   Integrate[100*x*pdf[x], {x, 0, 30}], 
    a]]

(* Maximize::natt: The maximum is not attained at any point 
    satisfying the given constraints. 

{∞, {a -> -∞}} *)
```

A lower bound must be placed on `a`. For example,

```
Assuming[a >= 0,
 Maximize[
  Integrate[400*(x - 2*a)*pdf[x], {x, 2*a, 30}] - 
   Integrate[100*x*pdf[x], {x, 0, 30}], 
    a]]

(* {4500, {a -> 0}} *)
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce  your latest code. 
`pdf[x_] = 
 PDF[UniformDistribution[{0, 30}], x] Assuming[a >= 0, 
   Maximize[
    Integrate[400*(x - 2*a)*pdf[x], {x, 2*a, 30}] - 
     Integrate[100*x*pdf[x], {x, 0, 30}], a]]` results in `Hold[Maximize...` and an error.

Comment: @user64494 - Works fine with v13.1 on my Mac. The presence of a `Hold` in your result seems odd.

Comment: I'm working in 13.1 on Windows 10.